# Add custom IIS handler

Tags: c#, .net, iis, handler

I'm facing issues in making a new handler (the very first I've ever tried) for IIS.
My setup is:

> IIS on Windows Server 2012
>   Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 (currently running php website)

This is the code of mt handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ProvaIISdotNET
{
    class myHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members
        public bool IsReusable {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            context.Response.Write("<html><body>Hi everybody!</body></html>");
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

On Visual Studio I made a new visual C# project > class library (.Net Framework)

1. added System.web to the references
2. compiled the code (release) for .NET 4
3. copied the dll file in <s>c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bin</s> `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`
4. <s>added the mapping path to test.test , test as 'name'.</s>
5. <s>In handler mapping > add managed handler I can't find the "myHandler" Type, even adding it manually the page at mysite/test.test get 404 not found.</s>
6. Edited my `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config` as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
        <add name="myhandler" path="/handled/*.my" verb="GET" type="ProvaIISdotNET.myHandler" />
    </handlers>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="home.html" />
                <add value="home.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When going to http://localhost/handled/test.my
I still get 404

What am I missing?

EDIT -20/2/2020- Edited to reflect the results after edits suggested by Jokies Ding

Answer (score 0):

This is how I deploy my handler.
1.Create a assembly project called "ProvaIISdotNET".

2.I remove the default class.cs and created my myHandler.cs

3.I copied the code like this. Since VS alarmed for system.linq and it is not require here, I removed it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ProvaIISdotNET
{
    class myHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            context.Response.Write("<html><body>Hi everybody!</body></html>");
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

4. I copy the release .dll to my site's root bin folder D:\mysite\bin (Please ensure you are placing the assembly in the root bin folder)
5. I added this to the root web.config system.webserver\handlers section. Please ensure no blank space " " have been placed in the end of type attribute.

   ```
    <handlers>
           <add name="myhandler" path="*" verb="GET" type="ProvaIISdotNET.myHandler" />
       </handlers>
   ```

6.I recycled the application pool.

Now its working on my side

[image]

Edit:

If the handler added correct, you will see this in C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC(siteID).

You could view the FRT log in IE

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still not working (question edited to reflect the new status)

Comment: @DDS. Could you get your handler work with a new created empty website? Please check  your  handler mappings->view order list. Promise your handler is on the top of  the order list. If static file handler have higher priority than your handler, then I will receive same error message.

Comment: The handler does not show up into the "handler selection" page website configuration. Anyway the site is a "test site" with just home.html and this.

Comment: @DDS You mean your handler didn't show up in your "handler mapping panel" or you can't view it in the "add manged handler"-> dropdownlist? Have you tried specify it via GUI? You can manual type in your handler type even it is not shown up. Besides, failed request tracing log would help us whether the handler has been called or not.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I mean I cant see it in the "add managed handler => droopdown", anyway I typed it in as suggested and now, at least, it's found (the error page tells the module is called), but it still throws a 404  Error Code    0x80070002

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

I had to enable the section by editing
`c:\windows\system32\inetserv\config\ApplicationHost.config`
changing the line
`<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` to `<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`
to enable the override of "handlers" section in web.config.

Also I confirm I had to add

```xml
<handlers>
  <add name="myhandler" 
     path="*" 
     verb="*" 
     type="ProvaIISdotNET.myHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

to web.config in the site root folder (not the webserver root), in my case  `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\` also I put in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\bin` the .dll file containing the handler's code